# What is a canvas not being shown?

Tags: canvas

I can't seem to figure out why a canvas is not being shown with this code, I have the JS file linked in HTML

// HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <hmtl>
        <head>
            <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <canvas id = "gameCanvas" width = "800" height = "600" style = "border: 1px"></canvas>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src = "main.js">
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>


// JAVASCRIPT file

function canvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var cavasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
    canvasContext.fillRect = (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}   

canvas();
```

Comment: You define the canvas in the <head>. It should go in the <body>.

Comment: why you have two html tags? is it a typo here?  remove this one `<hmtl>`